# Python Error with Co-registration Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, coregistration

When using the Co-registration plugin in QGIS 3.22.3, I get the following error about phython when trying to use both the Automated local and global co-registration tools. Here is the error:

*"Error loading Arosics, this plugin requires additional Python packages to work. For Windows users, download and reinstall the plugin with this zip all-in-one with all the libs and dependencies. Read the install instructions here:[https://github.com/SMByC/Coregistration-Qgis-processing#installation"](https://github.com/SMByC/Coregistration-Qgis-processing#installation%22)*

It seems it requires me to install something from that github link provided, but after I downloaded the file, its it a folder with many python files and I don't know how I should install them. I am using Windows 64 bit.

Anyone with a quick idea or quick instructions on how I can resolve this?

Comment: You need to install the plugin from the zip file